# Partial sum of probability of disjoint events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider the probability space $(X,\mathcal{M},P)$ and the disjoint sequence $\{A_n\} \subset \mathcal{M}$.

Claim: For any $0 <\epsilon <1$, there exists $N$ such that $P(\cup_{n \geq N+1} A_n) \leq \epsilon$.

For showing this, I think we can first relabel $A_n$'s such that if $i \leq j$, then $P(A_i) \geq P(A_j)$. Then, it makes sense that there should be an $N$ such that $P(\cup_{n \geq N+1} A_n) \leq \epsilon$ because otherwise we should probably be able to show that $P(\cup_{n \geq 1} A_n) >1$ which is a contradiction. But, I don't know how exactly I should write that. Any suggestion?

Comment: What other information do we have about $\{A_n\}_n$? Does it form a partition of $X$?

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis No other information. No, not necessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A\triangleq \bigcup_{n}A_n$. Observe that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$:

$$
P\left(\bigcup_{n\geq k}A_n\right) = P(A) - \sum_{n<k}P(A_k).
$$

Now, as $k\to \infty$ we have that $ \sum_{n<k}P(A_k) \to P(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

We note that $$ \sum \limits_{n = 0}^\infty P(A_n) = P\left(\cup_{n \geq 0} A_n \right) \leq 1.$$

In particular, this means that the infinite series $\sum P(A_n)$ converges; by definition, this means that for any $\epsilon > 0,$ there is an $N$ so that $$ P(\cup_{n \geq N+1} A_n ) = \sum\limits_{n \geq N+1} P(A_n) < \epsilon.$$